# PHP Add DateTime values together

Tags: php

I am trying to add two timeDates together with no luck so far, When i run the code below the value of TotalTime remains as '00:00:00' or i get the following error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string,

```
$TotalTime;
$CurrentTime = new DateTime('04:00:00');

$freshdateTime = new DateTime('00:00:00');
$freshdateTime->modify("+{$hours} hours");
$freshdateTime->modify("+{$mins} minutes");

echo $freshdateTime->format('H:i:s');

$Time_result = (strtotime($CurrentTime) + strtotime($freshdateTime));
$TotalTime = date('H:i:s',$Time_result);
echo ($TotalTime);
```

NOTE: ${hours} and ${mins} are set from values from a Database.
Any help is greatly appreciated!.

If more of code is needed i am more then happy to post whole PHP file.

Comment: You can't use DateTime objects with strtotime

Comment: What part of the error-message is not clear?

Comment: When you work with a predfined class, stick to that and use it's methods (for adding time in your case). Datetime has has method called `add`, that might be usefull in your case...

Comment: `DateTime::add(DateInterval $interval)` might be of use. (See the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) in the PHP docs)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff i will attempt to use that method and see how i go

Comment: Thank you @ccKep your comment has got me on the right track. If you wouldn't mind me ask you one more question, now that i am adding a DateInterval is it at all possible to have something like this:   $Time_result->add(new DateInterval($TimetoAdd)); where $TimetoAdd would be hours and minutes added by the user?

Comment: How you construct your `DateInterval` instance is totally up to you, ofcourse. `DateInterval::createFromDateString` ([Link](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)) comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah ok thanks agian i let you know how i go :) @ccKep

Comment: @ccKep I was making things way more complex then they needed to be In the end i have ended up just using 2 int vars and running a recursive function to work out hours etc but thank you for all of your help with this issue